# IBM worklight - "adapter not found, procedure invocation error"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am trying to implement form-based authentication using IBM worklight.
While executing it, it is showing 'adapter not found' & 'procedure invocation error'.

Kindly share the link to learn "IBM worklight" for beginners.

Comment: Check out following page: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fstart%2Fc_gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better to supply the full error that can be seen in the server logs as well as in Chrome's DevTools console.

Verify the following:

1. The adapter was indeed deployed, by right-clicking on the adapter folder and selecting Run As > Deploy adapter
2. That your adapter procedure invocation mentions the correct adapter name (check for spelling errors)

To learn more, visit the Developer Center: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-all-tutorials-7-0/